# How to stop gnuplot window poping-up when using it from command line in windows?

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, gnuplot

I am using perl to open a pipe to pgnuplot.exe to output plot commands. For example,

```
open ($PLOT, "|pgnuplot") or die "error: gnuplot not found!";

print $PLOT <<EOPLOT;

set term postscript eps enhanced "Arial" 20
set output "somefile.eps"

## do some plotting here ##

EOPLOT

close $PLOT;
```

I notice that a window for gnuplot always pops up and grabs the focus of my mouse and keyboard momentarily. This makes it difficult to use the computer while the plot script is running.

Is there any way to stop pgnuplot from opening a window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when starting a program in Windows (`CreateProcess` API) it is possible to request that the main window be hidden or minimized without focus (among other options).  But I don't know whether perl provides a easy way to do that.

You might consider using [batch operation](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_4.0/gnuplot.html#Batch%2fInteractive_Operation) instead (put your plot commands in a file, then pass the filename to gnuplot).

Comment: I just tried writing commands to a file and calling batch operation from perl. The effect is that the window now opens for a much shorter time but it still grabs the keyboard and mouse. Hence I can't type while running the plotting script in the background.

Comment: @devil: Did you try using `wgnuplot` instead of `pgnuplot` for batch operation?  `pgnuplot` is intended for use from other console programs, and will reuse the existing console window.  If your application isn't console mode, `pgnuplot` will create a new console, so use `wgnuplot` instead.

Comment: I changed pgnuplot to wgnuplot, no difference in behavior. I am calling perl from MSYS using a bash script. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: To add on, the window does not pop up with batch operation but the focus is still grabbed from the active window. I will post another question about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent showing child console windows via [Win32](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32) module:

```
use Win32;
Win32::SetChildShowWindow(0);
```