# How to stop gnuplot from grabbing focus of active window? (Windows)

Tags: perl, windows-7, gnuplot, msys

As a follow up to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335212/how-to-stop-gnuplot-window-poping-up-when-using-it-from-command-line-in-windows). I am calling pgnuplot using batch operation from a perl script, i.e. perl generates a plotting script, then it invokes gnuplot with the generated script and the output is a postscript file.

This causes the system's active window to momentarily lose focus whenever pgnuplot is called. Hence it is difficult to use the computer when the perl script is running. Is there a way to stop this behavior?

I am using Win 7 64bit and MSYS to invoke perl.

Comment: I dont know whether your problem is unique to windows, I use this in linux and my GUI doesnt lose focus. "gnuplot -rv -persist".

Comment: Indeed it is unique to not just windows but the version 4.2 that I was using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this to be a problem specific to gnuplot 4.2 on Windows 7. Updating to 4.4 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at my Windows machine right now, but `start` might have an option that will help. Check `start /?`. For example, starting gnuplot minimised might do the trick.

Comment: I'm running it in batch mode with an input script file. There's no gnuplot window showing, just that the current active window (any window) on screen has its focus disrupted momentarily.